# Python, server - client connection coroutine issues asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Been trying to create a server and client script that allows clients to connect to the server and join different rooms to chat. As of now everything is terminal based. The issue at hand is the following.

When a new clients connects to a existing room i get the following error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<ChatServer.handle_client() done, defined at C:\Users\~~~~\server.py:10> exception=TypeError('a coroutine was expected, got None')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\server.py", line 41, in handle_client
    await self.broadcast(f'{addr} has joined room {room}!\n', room, writer)
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\server.py", line 75, in broadcast
    task = asyncio.create_task(client.write(message.encode()))        
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 361, in create_task
    task = loop.create_task(coro)
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 438, in create_task
    task = tasks.Task(coro, loop=self, name=name)
TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got None
```

But, if the clients join separete rooms there is no error. If a client join an exists room with another client it inside, it gets that error. I have been trying to understand the error at hand but cant wrap my head around it.

Here is the code for the server:

```
import asyncio

#available_rooms = {"Room_1"}

class ChatServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = {}
        self.rooms = {}

    async def handle_client(self, reader, writer):
        addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
        print(f'Connected by {addr}')

        # Send the list of available rooms to the client
        available_rooms = '\n'.join(self.rooms.keys())
        print("---->" + available_rooms)
        writer.write(f'Available Rooms: {available_rooms}\n'.encode())
        await writer.drain()

        while True:
            message = await reader.readline()
            if not message:
                break
            message = message.decode().strip()
            command = message.split()[0]

            if command == "LIST":
                available_rooms = '\n'.join(self.rooms.keys())
                writer.write(f'Available Rooms: {available_rooms}\n'.encode())
                await writer.drain()
            elif command == "JOIN":
                room = message.split()[1]
                if room not in self.rooms:
                    writer.write(f"{room} room not found. creating it\n".encode())
                    self.rooms[room] = []
                    await writer.drain()
                self.clients[writer] = room
                self.rooms[room].append(writer)
                writer.write(f'You joined room: {room}!\n'.encode())
                await writer.drain()
                await self.broadcast(f'{addr} has joined room {room}!\n', room, writer)

            elif command == "LEAVE":
                if writer not in self.clients:
                    writer.write(f'You are not currently in a room!\n'.encode())
                    await writer.drain()
                else:
                    room = self.clients[writer]
                    writer.write(f'You left room {room}!\n'.encode())
                    await writer.drain()
                    self.clients.pop(writer)
                    self.rooms[room].remove(writer)
                    await self.broadcast(f'{addr} has left room {room}!\n', room, writer)

                    # remove the room if it is empty
                    if not self.rooms[room]:
                        self.rooms.pop(room)
            else:
                try:
                    await self.broadcast(f'{addr}: {message}\n', self.clients[writer], writer)
                except KeyError:
                    writer.write(f'You are not currently in a room!\n'.encode())
                    await writer.drain()
                    continue

        print(f'Disconnected {addr}')
        writer.close()


    async def broadcast(self, message, room, sender):
        tasks = []
        for client in self.rooms[room]:
            # exclude sender from broadcast
            if client != sender:
                task = asyncio.create_task(client.write(message.encode()))
                tasks.append(task)
        if tasks:
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


    def start(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        coro = asyncio.start_server(self.handle_client, '127.0.0.1', 5323, loop=loop)
        #coro = asyncio.start_server(self.handle_client, '10.44.33.158', 5000, loop=loop)
        server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

        # Serve requests until Ctrl+C is pressed
        print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
        try:
            loop.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

        # Close the server
        server.close()
        loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
        loop.close()

server = ChatServer()
server.start()
```

And here is the code for the client:

```
import asyncio

class ChatClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.room = None

    async def start(self, host, port):
        self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)

        # Get the list of available rooms
        available_rooms = await self.reader.readline()
        print(available_rooms.decode())

        self.writer.write('JOIN myroom_2\n'.encode())
        await self.writer.drain()
        resp = await self.reader.readline()
        if resp:
            print(resp.decode())
        self.room = "myroom_2"

        while True:
            message = await self.reader.readline()
            print(message.decode())

            message_to_send = input()
            if message_to_send == "LEAVE":
                self.writer.write("LEAVE\n".encode())
                await self.writer.drain()
                print("left the room")
                break
            elif message_to_send.startswith("JOIN"):
                _, new_room = message_to_send.split()
                self.writer.write(f"JOIN {new_room}\n".encode())
                await self.writer.drain()
                resp = await self.reader.readline()
                if resp:
                    print(resp.decode())
                self.room = new_room
                continue
            elif message_to_send == "LIST":
                self.writer.write("LIST\n".encode())
                await self.writer.drain()
                response = await self.reader.readline()
                print(response.decode())
                continue
            self.writer.write(f"{message_to_send}\n".encode())
            await self.writer.drain()

            
    async def list_rooms(self):
        self.writer.write("LIST\n".encode())
        await self.writer.drain()
        try:
            response = await asyncio.wait_for(self.reader.readline(), timeout=5)
            print(response.decode())
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("timeout reached while waiting for a response")

    
    async def change_room(self):
        self.writer.write("Enter new room name:\n".encode())
        await self.writer.drain()
        new_room = input()
        self.writer.write(f"JOIN {new_room}\n".encode())
        await self.writer.drain()
        response = await self.reader.readline()
        print(response.decode())
        self.room = new_room
    
    async def write(self, message):
        self.writer.write(message.encode())
        await self.writer.drain()

client = ChatClient()
asyncio.run(client.start('127.0.0.1',5323 ))
```

I have tried different write methods but nothing works, unable to wrap my head around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how you are using `asyncio.create_task`.

In the `Server.broadcast` function you call:

```py
task = asyncio.create_task(client.write(message.encode()))
```

`asyncio.create_task` expects a coroutine but you are giving it a normal funciton. `client` in this context will be a [`asyncio.StreamWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#streamwriter), and the `write` method is a normal function. you should probably create a task from the `client.drain` coroutine:

```py
client.write(message.encode())
task = asyncio.create_task(client.drain())
```